# Spring - How to get reference to TransactionStatus object in a Transactional method

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

When using `@Transactional` in a service layer, is there any option to get a reference to the `TransactionStatus` instance created by the `PlatformTransactionManager`?

For instance, in the following code :

```
@Transactional
public void updateCustomer(...) {
    // do some business stuff
    // can we get here a reference to the TransactionStatus instance ?
}
```

Comment: What do you need it for? I have been writing transactional spring code for years without needing to manually set or query a TransactionStatus ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
TransactionStatus status = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();
```

The [`currentTransactionStatus`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport.html#currentTransactionStatus--) method returns the transaction status of the current method invocation.

If you are interested in the result of a transaction, you could consider the [`TransactionSynchronizationAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationAdapter.html) which provides a convenient [`afterCompletion(int status)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationAdapter.html#afterCompletion-int-) callback:

```
class AfterCompletionTransactionHandler
        extends TransactionSynchronizationAdapter {

    public @Override void afterCompletion(int status) { ... }

}
```

Comment: This answer is IMHO incorrect. I am inside a transactional method and execute JPA queries. But when I run `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus()` in this method, I get `org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException: No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope`